# jQuery validate with many select-multiple fields (with Django)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, multi-select

My form has automatically generated multiselect fields. This means I don't know how many of them will be created (depends on input file). Also, select name cannot be used since its autogenerated in a specific way, so I guess in jQuery I'd have to go with either class or ID.

I've already tried few options I found on stackoverflow etc, and the best of what I could get to was my code below. It actually validates if there is at least one option selected, but across all of presented multiselect fields. So if I have 10 fields, in one of them one was selected, thats enough for submit button to work, which is not what I want.

Theres the jQuery part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#myForm').submit(function () {
                    var isValid = true;
                    var form = this;
                    isValid = isValid && validateMultipleSelect($('select.required', form));
                    return isValid;
                });
            });
            function validateMultipleSelect(select) {
                var number = $('option:selected', select).size();
                alert("Select at least one option in each column per Vendor")
                return (number > 0);
            }
        </script>
```

Now this is the Form part:

```
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post" id="myForm">
            {% csrf_token %}
        <p></p>
        <hr>
​
        {% for vendor in vendor_list %}
             {{ vendor.vendor_name }} 
   ​
                    {% for columns in vendor.option_list %}
​
                        <select class="required" multiple id="required" name = '{{ columns.column_name }} {{ vendor.vendor_id }}'>
                            <option value = {{ columns.column_name }} disabled> {{ columns.column_name }}</option>
                                {% for option in columns.column_options %}
                                <option value= "{{ option }}"> {{ option }} </option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            <br>
                        </select>
​
​
                     {% endfor %}
            <br><br>
​
        {% endfor %}
```

I did try to pull the length of how many multiple select fields I have, so if I have 10 select fields, then the condition could be 'at least 10 options selected'. But if from multiple select fields one of them has 10 options, 10 could be selected in that select field and zero options can be selected in any other select field, that would still let the submit button work (since 10 options were selected), which is not what I want.

What I need is to validate each of select fields for at least ONE selected option. So in all of those select fields at least one option have to be selected in order to make submit button work.

So this shouldn't work (since last row's country isnt selected):

[image]

And this should work:

[image]

thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok someone helped me, this works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#myForm').submit(function () {
                var isValid = true;
                $('select.required').each((index, element) => {
                    var isValid = validateMultipleSelect(element);
                    if (!isValid) {
                        alert("Select at least one option in each column per vendor");
                        event.preventDefault()
                        return isValid;

                    }
                });
                return isValid;

            });
        });
        function validateMultipleSelect(select) {
            var number =$('option:selected', select).size();
            return (number >0);
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: No problem Piotr, happy to help